# Regex - Capture multiline pattern - the shortest match

Tags: regex

[My test result in regexr dot com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvrFp.png)

I'm trying to capture the shortest match in multiline text, and stop check if the beginning pattern appears again before the whole pattern is found.

Pattern with issue:

```
    test2(.|\n)*?test4
```

Input:

```
    1       test1
    2       test2
    5       test5
    6       test1
    7       test2
    8       test3
    9       test4
    10      test5
    11      test1
    12      test2
    13      test3
    14      test4
    15      test5
```

Expected 2 result:
First: line 7 till line 9
Second: line 12 till line 14

Actual (unwanted) result:
First: line 2 till line 9
Second: line 12 till line 14

Answer (score 1):

The `(.|\n)*?` is non greedy, but it can also match any characters including any form of the test string.

What you might do is limit the accepted `test` string by allowing only digits 2, 3 or 4 and make the non capture group non greedy to get the "shortest" match.

```
test2(?:\n.*test[234])*?\n.*test4
```

The pattern matches:

- `test2` match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\n.*test[234]` Match a newline and in the line `test` followed by a digit 2, 3 or 4
- `)*?` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat non greedy
- `\n.*test4` Match a newline and a line that matches test4

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7qfV2i/1).

Comment: Seems my test sample is not good. Here's the actual data.
See: [link](https://regex101.com/r/g1OJH1/1/)
<br>
`level=Info(?:(.|\n)*?(^level=|sec"$))`
The "unselected" ones are the actual data I would like to capture. from **level=Info**, ended with **sec"**